# React - Image Uploader only allow transparent images

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mern

I want to check the image alpha channel to see if it has a background, and reject it if true, allow it if false but when I upload an image using the const `changefile`, the `hasAlpha` function doesn't serve an 'error' alert if the image has a background.

Function for checking if the image has a transparent background:

```
export function hasAlpha(file) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let hasAlpha = false;
    const canvas = document.querySelector("canvas");
    const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

    const img = new Image();
    img.crossOrigin = "Anonymous";
    img.onerror = reject;
    img.onload = function () {
      canvas.width = img.width;
      canvas.height = img.height;

      ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
      const imgData = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height).data;

      for (let j = 0; j < imgData.length; j += 4) {
        if (imgData[j + 3] < 255) {
          hasAlpha = true;
          break;
        }
      }
      resolve(hasAlpha);
    };
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
  });
}
```

Where the image is uploaded:

```
    const changefile = async (e) => {
      if (e.target.id === "mainImg") {
        1;
        let file = e.target.files[0] ? e.target.files[0] : "";
    
        if (file) {
          let extension = file.name.substr(file.name.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
          if (validExtensions.includes(extension)) {
            setTempImg(URL.createObjectURL(file));
            setstate({
              ...state,
              image: file
            });
            if (hasAlpha(URL.createObjectURL(file))) {
              alert(hasAlpha(URL.createObjectURL(file)));
            } else {
              alert("error");
            }
          } else {
            setstate({
              ...state,
              image: ""
            });
          }
        } else {
          setstate({
        ...state,
        image: ""
      });
      setTempImg("");
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: `hasAlpha` is returning a`Promise`. `hasAlpha(URL.createObjectURL(file)).then((alpha) => {  } ).catch((e) => console.log(e))`;

Comment: ` if (await hasAlpha(URL.createObjectURL(file))) // await promise`

Comment: Thanks @AmirSaleem . Are you able to work your solution into the code and submit an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am here from your Google Docs bug. I have already sent a proposal to you. I tested this code. If it doesn't work in your project, it means another bug exists in your React project. To solve those bugs I need to see your whole react component code.

```
function hasAlpha(file) {
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const img = new Image()

    // create image from file
    img.src = URL.createObjectURL(file)

    img.onerror = reject

    img.onload = () => {
        // create canvas
        const canvas = document.createElement('canvas')
        const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d')
        canvas.width = img.width
        canvas.height = img.height
        ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0)

        // get image data
        const data = ctx.getImageData(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)

        // check if image has any transparent background
        const hasTransparent = [...data.data].some((value, index) => {
            return index % 4 === 3 && value < 255
        })

        return hasTransparent ? resolve(true) : resolve(false)
    }
})}
```

You have to wait before hasAlpha() resolve or reject. So, you should call `await hasAlpha(file)` and wrap entire call with try catch. If promise rejected you can access it in catch block.

```
try {
  if(await hasAlpha(file)) {
    // promise resloved, image is transparent
  } else {
    // promise resloved, image is not transparent
  }
} catch (e) {
 // promise rejected
}
```